# Creating a library and executable in a single project

Tags: rust

How do I create a library and executable in one project? I just want to test my library while working on it and using tests isn't always the best way to do that. I believe I have to use `[lib]` and `[???]` but I haven't found the information about that at crates.io.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it's strange that crates.io does not have a clear example of this.

To add both a library and an executable to your crate (BTW, the crate can only have one library in it), you need to defined them in `[lib]` and `[[bin]]` sections:

```
[lib]
name = "yourcrate"

[[bin]]
name = "yourcrate_bin_1"

[[bin]]
name = "yourcrate_bin_2"
```

With the above by default Cargo will look for the library crate root in `src/lib.rs` and for binaries in `src/bin/yourcrate_bin_1.rs` and `src/bin/yourcrate_bin_2.rs`. You can change paths to the crate root files with `path` option:

```
[[bin]]
name = "yourcrate_bin_2"
path = "src/yourcrate_bin_2.rs"
```

Comment: what does bin has the double "[["?

Comment: That's because multiple `bin` sections are possible. See [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) description for more information, in particular, [this](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#array-of-tables) section.